# CSS inch/mm measurements not accurate

Tags: html, css, printing, label

I am currently developing a tool for printing labels from the browser. I am running in to an interesting issue where I have labels that are 2.25" x 1.25". As such I have set my print CSS for a div to `width: 2.25in; height: 2.25in;`

In the chrome inspector, the dimensions appear properly as 2.25in; by 1.25in. Also, my printer is configured correctly as the same coordinates exactly.

When the time comes to print I am actually getting a preview that does not fill the entire 2.25x1.25 print preview.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/73ZCR.png

The dotted border is the border of the 2.25x1.25 inch div. Completely inaccurate measurement.

Any advice or tips on what could be going wrong? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

One inch in CSS (`1 in`) is defined as 96 pixels ([source](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths)).
This works on low-density devices where 1 physical pixel = 1 screen pixel.

On high-dpi (dots per inch) devices like printers, it doesn't really work, though.

---

Seing as you want it to fill the whole viewport, maybe you should take a look at the `vh` and `vw` units.
They're described [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#relative-lengths).

`vh` stands for viewport-height and `vw` (you guessed it) stands for viewport-width.

Long story short, `1 vh = 1% of screen height`, same for `vw` (except it's the width).

Comment: Unfortunately this was not the fix, but thank you because you did get me a step closer! Now I am properly accounting for the 96DPI to 203DPI calculations when specifying my parameters of the Zebra printer, but I found the DPI from the printer manual, and the coordinates still don't appear properly. (Too big for the label now).

Comment: wait, what? I assumed that 1 inch would be defined as the dpi of the device!